# Change Docker disk space on macOS

Tags: macos, docker

I installed Docker 1.13 on macOS 10.10, logged in the docker "machine" with

```
screen ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/tty
```

And did a df -h. It says I have a /dev/sda1 mounted on /var/lib/docker/overlay2 with 64 GB of disk space.

```
/dev/sda1                62.7G      5.6G     54.0G   9% /var/lib/docker/overlay2
```

I had a few builds failing for "no space left on device" so I suspect this is where all images end up going.

What is not clear to me is the following:

1. what is this /dev/sda1. Is it a virtual image disk somewhere on my mac? if so, where?
2. Suppose I am running out of space and I want to store more images. How does one increase this disk space?

Answer (score 4):

Not enough rep for a comment.

Docker Desktop 2.0 on MacOSX allows you to change the size of the disc in the GUI. Go to Preferences->Disk and increase the disc image size.

Answer (score 1):

1) This is a VM disk image stored in the same directory as the `tty` socket you mentioned: `~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/Docker.qcow2`

2) AFAIK it's not possible to resize this existing disk, you'll need to recreate a blank VM disk with a larger size:

```
$ cd ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/database/
$ git reset --hard
HEAD is now at c435935 Settings Changed 09 Jan 17 20:28 +0000

$ cat com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/disk/size
65536
$ echo 153600 > com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/disk/size  # size in MiB
$ git add com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/disk/size
$ git commit -s -m 'New target disk size'
$ rm ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/Docker.qcow2
```

Then restart Docker.

Source: https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/1118#issuecomment-271399701

Answer (score 0):

Daniel's answer is right but I found an easier solution. In my case, I think I did migrate from docker-toolbox back in the days which locked by database to ~17G. I found it easier to follow these instructions:
https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/135#issuecomment-248009571

Note that *this will delete your containers*:

1. Stop docker for mac
2. `rm ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/Docker.qcow2`
3. Start docker for mac

It seemed to work on my side. [The github issue comment above](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/135#issuecomment-248009571) mentions [`docker save`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/) and [`docker load`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/load/) commands that let you backup your containers before nuking your `Docker.qcow2`. I didn't use them since I didn't really care about my containers.